# Unable to apply Template to new work items

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have created a new Bug template on Azure Dev Ops under `/_settings/work-team?type=Bug&_a=templates`, to allow pre-population of 2 fields on a bug ticket with templated headings. We have this working with our on-prem TFS 2019, and users know to click `...` > `Templates` > `New Bug`. I'm trying to replicate this over into ADO to keep tickets consistent, but when I click `...` for the context menu in ADO, `Templates` don't appear.

TFS:

[image]

ADO:

[image]

How do I get the `Templates` context-menu item to show on new tickets?

Comment: Which ADO version? Azure DevOps cloud service or ADO server 2020/2022? The template option is default option. Please F12 to launch developer tool, then replicate the appearance, is there any message on the network trace? In addition, follow [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/item-templates-are-not-visible/1368558#T-N1369468) for a check the permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding myself as an explicit user to each team for which I want to use the templates. Thanks to `wade-zhou-msft` for the tip-off.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you! You can mark your reply as answer so that it can help others who has the same issue, thanks

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I had to wait 48hrs to mark it, which I've now done.